# Smoothly move a sprite in update() while allowing manual moving

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to smoothly move a sprite through my screen, and *not* have it tied to the framerate of the game. For this I'm using `clock.tick()`:

```
def main(fps):
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(640, 480)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    ball = Block(pygame.Color('white'), 16, 16)  # Block defined later

    # Main loop
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running= False
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
        screen.blit(ball.image, ball.rect)
        dt = clock.tick(fps)
        ball.update(dt=dt)
```

And here's my `Block` class:

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed = pygame.math.Vector2()

    def update(self, dt):
        dt /= 1000  # ms -> s
        self.rect.move_ip(dt * self.speed.x, dt * self.speed.y)
```

The problem is that `dt` turns out to be so small that `dt * self.speed.x` ends up being less than `1` and rectangle's position has to be integers, thus it doesn't move the rectangle at all.

I fixed this by adding `self._position` attribute which stores an internal "hidden" position which can be float, and then I changed the `update()` method to this:

```
def update(self, dt):
    dt /= 1000
    self._position[0] += dt * self.speed.x
    self._position[1] += dt * self.speed.y
    self.rect.x = round(self._position[0])
    self.rect.y = round(self._position[1])
```

However, if anyone changes the rect manually outside of `update()` method, his changes will not effect the rect as the next `update()` resets the position. Is there any standard approach to this?

Comment: Why do you divide by 1000? I would try to either remove the division or tune the divisor for better results, based on values of speed.x and speed.y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-assigning `self.rect` based on the "hidden" float values you have stored.

```
def update(self, dt):
    dt /= 1000
    self._position[0] += dt * self.speed.x
    self._position[1] += dt * self.speed.y
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self._position[0], self._position[1], self.image.get_width(), self.image.get_height())
```

To change the location manually, use a method that updates`self._position` and then re-assignes a new `pygame.Rect()`.

```
def set_location(self, x, y):
    self._position[0] = x
    self._position[1] = y
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self._position[0], self._position[1], self.image.get_width(), self.image.get_height())
```